# Resize Flash Object

Tags: html, flash, resize, embed

i trying to resize the height of a flash object to the size of a divider.
This actually does not work, so what's wrong here? The flash object is displayed, but it's height is only 100px.
I want to resize the movie later by calling the js-method from flash and change the size of the div object.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.Pages.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div align="center">
            <div id="contentDivider" style="width:780;height:600;">
                <object width="780" height="100%">
                  <embed src="../content/Home.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="780" height="100%" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://get.adobe.com/de/flashplayer/"></embed>
                </object>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function setFlashHeight(height) {
            contentDivider.style.height = height;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers
Felix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to create a resizable flash object via html drag some time ago, this was my solution:

- I created the flash object with % dimensions, e.g height:100%;
- And I resized the flash html container  and the flash should
  follow the div's height.

Let me know if it works for you.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<div style="height:500px;">
<object style='height:100%;'><embed/></object>
</div>
```

Resize the `div` and it should be fine

Comment: Thanks, that helped.
I changed the width and height property to style values and added 'px' to my height and width values ( i think this has been the issue ).

Comment: I noticed it is not working on the IE, any suggestions on that?

Comment: That is strange. Mine is working cross-browser. Check your doc-type, and recheck your html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/

Swffit (formerly know as FitFlash) is a smart script that resizes your flash movie automatically if your browser window size is smaller or greater than your flash minimum desired size keeping it accessible independent of screen resolution.

It seems to have a lot of features, including resize events.